# Can an out of state driver's license be used to verify DOB in Illinois for a state ID?

Tags: illinois, identification

The [DMV page](https://www.dmv.org/il-illinois/id-cards.php#IL-ID-Card-Eligibility-Requirements) to apply for a state ID or driver's license in Illinois states that you need to bring proof of your date of birth to obtain an ID card. It links to an [acceptable documents PDF](https://www.cyberdriveillinois.com/publications/pdf_publications/dsd_x173.pdf) which under Group B specifies that an "Illinois Driver's License" is one acceptable form of identification among a handful of others. It does not list out of state identification. Below this list it states

> Group B documents must contain the applicant’s full name and complete date of birth and must be verifiable. To be verifiable, it must be possible to contact the regulatory authority to confirm the authenticity of the document.

The PDF specifically says "**Illinois** Driver's License" but my out of state license lists my full name, date of birth, and it certainly seems like it should be verifiable by their definition.
Can an out of state license be used as proof of date of birth? If it cannot be used, why?

Comment: This  can be answered by people in 50 states because they are all going off the list of acceptable documents required by Homeland for the Real-ID program.  Many states just require the same docs for non-Real-ID licenses and ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PDF you linked also lists "REAL ID Driver’s License/ID Card" as an acceptable document in Group B. So, it seems that an out-of-state driver's license may be used to verify DOB, but *only* if it complies with the REAL ID requirements. Apparently, all 50 states are now issuing REAL IDs, but only 38% of all licenses nationwide are currently REAL ID compliant.

Comment: Maybe out of scope for this question then, but why does real id compliance matter for verifying date of birth?

Comment: @qfwfq The REAL ID requirements set a minimum security standard for producing and issuing licenses that each state must follow. IDs that do not comply with REAL ID standards do not meet these requirements, and are presumably less secure. They are no longer valid in instances like this, or when boarding a plane, or various other instances where the integrity of the license is important.

Comment: I suppose, although it seems odd to me that the only difference in terms of application is a second document proving residence (unless I'm missing something). Based on the "Group D" documents it seems like the only thing the real id is showing is whether the person also bought a phone book. I'll stop grumbling though, thanks for the answer.